# How to fix loadmore-scroll problem on pages refreshed with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll

I created a photos share page which refreshs with ajax. The page has 3 links (allphotos, high quality photos, poor quality photos). When clicking each of them, datas(photos) are loading with ajax. And after scrolling, ajax provides to bring more photo. each page (because of filtering ) has different javascript functions which are allphotos() and gallery(). Both have same scroll event function. After scrolling down, datas started to become confused. One gets data from function allphoto and one gets data from function gallery() I cant solve how to fix this. Here are my javascript and php codes.

(Codes diveded 2 main part, one has javacript codes and php codes which related each others)

### javascript page (app.js)

```
function allphotos(){


    open_popup();
    var limit_load = 5;
    var start_load = 0;
    var action = "inactive"

    function load_photo_profile(limit_load, start_load) {

        var url = baseUrl+"exhibition/loadmore";


        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            data: { limit: limit_load, start: start_load },
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == '') {
                    $("#included_image_message").html("<h1>No data found</h1>");
                    action = "active";

                } else {
                    $(".included_image").append(response);
                    $("#included_image_message").html("<h1>Please Wait</h1>");

                    action = "inactive";
                }



            }
        });


    };

    if (action == "inactive") {
        action = "active";
        load_photo_profile(limit_load, start_load);
    }



    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + 250 >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() && action == "inactive" && localStorage.getItem("scroll") == "all") {

            action = "active";

            start_load = start_load + limit_load;

            setTimeout(() => {
                load_photo_profile(limit_load, start_load);

            }, 500);

        }
    });


}
```

```
function gallery(){


    var limit_load = 5;
    var start_load = 0;
    var action = "inactive"

    function load_photo_profile(limit_load, start_load) {

        var url = baseUrl + "exhibition/gallery";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            data: { limit: limit_load, start: start_load },
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == '') {

                    $("#included_image_message").html("<h1>No data found</h1>");
                    action = "active";

                } else {

                    $(".included_image").append(response);
                    $("#included_image_message").html("<h1>Please Wait</h1>");

                    action = "inactive";
                }



            }
        });


    };

    if (action == "inactive") {
        action = "active";
        load_photo_profile(limit_load, start_load);
    }



    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + 250 >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() && action == "inactive" && localStorage.getItem("scroll") == "all") {

            action = "active";

            start_load = start_load + limit_load;
            setTimeout(() => {
                load_photo_profile(limit_load, start_load);

            }, 500);

        }
    });





}
```

### control.php (only in order to get data from db) (codeigniter)

```
public function loadmore()
    {
        $limit = $this->input->post("limit");
        $start = $this->input->post("start");






        $viewData = new StdClass();
        $viewData->viewFolder = $this->viewFolder;
        $viewData->subViewFolder = "profile";


        $get_images = $this->photo_model->get_all_limit(
            array(
                "Durum"     => 1
            ),
            "Id DESC",
            $limit,
            $start
        );

        if (!$get_images == "") {
            $viewData->items = $get_images;
            $activeUser=get_active_user();
            $viewData->activeUser = $activeUser;

            $render_html = $this->load->view("{$viewData->viewFolder}/assist/mygallery", $viewData, true);
            echo $render_html;
        }
    }
```

```
function gallery()
    {
        $limit = $this->input->post("limit");
        $start = $this->input->post("start");

        $viewData = new StdClass();
        $viewData->viewFolder = $this->viewFolder;
        $viewData->subViewFolder = "profile";


        $get_images = $this->photo_model->get_all_limit(
            array(
                "Durum"         => 1,
                "Tur"           => 1
            ),
            "Id DESC",
            $limit,
            $start
        );

        if (!$get_images == "") {
            $viewData->items = $get_images;
            $activeUser = get_active_user();
            $viewData->activeUser = $activeUser;



            $render_html = $this->load->view("{$viewData->viewFolder}/assist/mygallery", $viewData, true);
            echo $render_html;
        }
    }
```

In my opinion in spide of loading refreshing ajax, the codes at below confuses because of the scroll event execute already at same page

```
$(window).scroll(function (){
       if ($(window).scrollTop() + 250 >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() && action == "inactive" && localStorage.getItem("scroll") == "all") {

           action = "active";

           start_load = start_load + limit_load;
           setTimeout(() => {
               load_photo_profile(limit_load, start_load);

           }, 500);

       }
   });
```

Comment: Try to reduce the size of the question and focus on your problem.

Comment: I did not able to find an easy way so that declare

Comment: At least, try to make your code more organized.